# Differential Equation with a Fraction

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

While attempting to solve a physics problem, I ran into the following differential equation: $$y''=a\cdot\frac{by}{c+by}$$
where all the constants are nonzero. I am completely stumped as to how I could solve this. I'm not even sure if it's solvable analytically.

I've tried rearranging the equation to perhaps gain some insights, but neither $$cy''+byy''=aby$$ nor $$y=\frac{cy''}{ab-by''}$$ seem to be helpful.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think it has a closed form solution? Have you performed any numerical methods to see how it behaves?

Comment: The physics problem it arises from suggests it would have a sinusoidal solution.

Comment: Notice that $$a\cdot\frac{by}{c+by}=a\cdot\frac{y}{\frac{c}{b}+y}:=a\cdot\frac{y}{d+y}=a\cdot\frac{d+y-d}{d+y}=a-\frac{ad}{d+y},$$ with $d:=\frac{c}{b}.$ The reason I show you this is because now you have $$y''=a-\frac{ad}{d+y},$$ which you can order-reduce by multiplying by $2y'$ as follows: $$2y'y''=(y'^2)'=2ay'-\frac{2ady'}{d+y}=(2ay-\ln[\pm(d+y)])',$$ which implies $$y'^2=2ay-\ln[-(d+y)]+A$$ for $y\lt-d,$ or $$y'^2=2ay-\ln(d+y)+B$$ for $y\gt-d.$ However, we are at an impasse, as I do not believe either of these questions can be solved analytically in closed-form.

Comment: Oops, I made a mistake above, there should be a coefficient of $2ad$ next to each of the logarithms above. I cannot edit my comment, though, as it has been more than 5 minutes since I wrote it. Still, my point stands: it seems there is no exact solution expressible in terms of well-studied functions. To my knowledge, there is no nice way of expressing the antiderivatives of $$\frac1{\sqrt{Cy-Cd\ln(d+y)+D}}$$ for nonzero values of $C,d,D.$ You said this is a physics problem, but this really may require numerical methods to solve approximately, which would not be unheard of from physics.

Comment: One can find a closed form for $x$ as a function of $y$ which involves a function defined by an integral. But one cannot find the inverse function $y(x)$ from $x(y)$ with a finite number of standard functions. So we would have to use numerical calculus for the integral and then for the inversion. It is probably simpler to use numerical calculus to directly solve the differential equation.

Comment: This also depends from the boundary conditions. Eventually, but rarely, simplification might occur in case of particular boundary conditions making possible the analytical solving. For more help you should add the boundary conditions to your question.